# Stencil Theme upload fails after processing

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

Before getting too far into developing my theme, which is based on Cornerstone, I have tried running the `stencil bundle` command and then uploading the customized Cornerstone theme onto my bigcommerce website. It finishes uploading and gets a small portion of the loading bar finished before telling me "There was a problem processing the theme". I'm not sure what I missed in the stencil documentation. Maybe I have made adjustments to a file that shouldn't have been changed, such as the Foundation settings file? If you could help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: can you check the developer console for a suppressed error?

Comment: Checking the terminal where I typed in `stencil start` I get warnings about utility classes. I'm not sure what you mean by developer console - is it the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: I have some large files (a video header). I didn't put them in the `cdn` folder. I'll try that next. (never mind, that was only if the theme was larger than 50MB which it isn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my videos into the `cdn` folder and it uploaded fine.